# How to solve compilation error when using scala.sys.process._

Tags: scala

I'm using Scala maven plugin to compile Scala code and I'm getting the following error when trying to execute a bash command. I understand that I don't necessarily need to use curl to do a get request but this error is just a killer. Can someone help with the sorting out this classpath issue?

```
[ERROR] /Users/..... error: Symbol 'term shaded.v245' is missing from the classpath.
[ERROR] This symbol is required by ' <none>'.
[ERROR] Make sure that term v245 is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[ERROR] A full rebuild may help if 'RunId.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of shaded.
[ERROR]     Seq("curl", "-n", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "GET", "-d", runID, urlRunsGet)!!
[ERROR]        ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Scala version 2.11.12.

Comment: I don't quite understand what I'd need to rebuild. I'm not sure where `RunId` comes from. I do have `runID` on the call which is String.

Comment: The curl works OK and this code runs in repl and in a notebook on server. This is a compile time error.

Comment: It seems from your error that you are shading `Seq`. Do you have somewhere in your file `type Seq = ...`?

Comment: No there's no such code, though it could come from dependencies. I've tried commenting all the process calling code and then the same error spilled to other code.

Comment: Then please create a [mre], andn even better provide a [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/) link. Otherwise it will be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by adding:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbutils-api_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

without adding:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Adding both solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you import both `postfixOps` and `process._` it should work.

Complete working example:

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.sys.process._

Seq("curl", "-n", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "GET", "-d", "runID", "urlRunsGet")!!
```

Which produces in both [Scala 2.11](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/qdLUNwSFS3qNEzDTQhEyDQ/4), and [Scala 2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/qdLUNwSFS3qNEzDTQhEyDQ/2):

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": error=2, No such file or directory
```

and shows that the code compiles.